# Still vulnerable after SpectreMeltdown ubuntu kernel 3.13.0-141-generic update?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, security

I have updated my server with ubuntu 14.04 to the newest kernel:

```
3.13.0-141-generic
```

Which is the second release after the disclosure of the spectreMeltdown vulnerability as far as i can tell.

But when running the spectre-and-meltdown vulnerability checker:

https://github.com/speed47/spectre-meltdown-checker

My system still seems vulnerable:

```
Spectre and Meltdown mitigation detection tool v0.32

Checking for vulnerabilities on current system
Kernel is Linux 3.13.0-141-generic #190-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 19 12:52:38 UTC 2018 x86_64
CPU is Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630L v2 @ 2.40GHz

Hardware check
* Hardware support (CPU microcode) for mitigation techniques
  * Indirect Branch Restricted Speculation (IBRS)
    * SPEC_CTRL MSR is available:  NO
    * CPU indicates IBRS capability:  NO
  * Indirect Branch Prediction Barrier (IBPB)
    * PRED_CMD MSR is available:  NO
    * CPU indicates IBPB capability:  NO
  * Single Thread Indirect Branch Predictors (STIBP)
    * SPEC_CTRL MSR is available:  NO
    * CPU indicates STIBP capability:  NO
  * Enhanced IBRS (IBRS_ALL)
    * CPU indicates ARCH_CAPABILITIES MSR availability:  NO
    * ARCH_CAPABILITIES MSR advertises IBRS_ALL capability:  NO
  * CPU explicitly indicates not being vulnerable to Meltdown (RDCL_NO):  NO
* CPU vulnerability to the three speculative execution attacks variants
  * Vulnerable to Variant 1:  YES
  * Vulnerable to Variant 2:  YES
  * Vulnerable to Variant 3:  YES

CVE-2017-5753 [bounds check bypass] aka 'Spectre Variant 1'
* Checking count of LFENCE opcodes in kernel:  YES
> STATUS:  NOT VULNERABLE  (99 opcodes found, which is >= 70, heuristic to be improved when official patches become available)

CVE-2017-5715 [branch target injection] aka 'Spectre Variant 2'
* Mitigation 1
  * Kernel is compiled with IBRS/IBPB support:  YES
  * Currently enabled features
    * IBRS enabled for Kernel space:  NO  (echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/ibrs_enabled)
    * IBRS enabled for User space:  NO  (echo 2 > /proc/sys/kernel/ibrs_enabled)
    * IBPB enabled:  NO  (echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/ibpb_enabled)
* Mitigation 2
  * Kernel compiled with retpoline option:  NO
  * Kernel compiled with a retpoline-aware compiler:  NO
  * Retpoline enabled:  NO
> STATUS:  VULNERABLE  (IBRS hardware + kernel support OR kernel with retpoline are needed to mitigate the vulnerability)

CVE-2017-5754 [rogue data cache load] aka 'Meltdown' aka 'Variant 3'
* Kernel supports Page Table Isolation (PTI):  YES
* PTI enabled and active:  YES
* Running as a Xen PV DomU:  NO
> STATUS:  NOT VULNERABLE  (PTI mitigates the vulnerability)

A false sense of security is worse than no security at all, see --disclaimer
```

[image: https://imgur.com/a/tobCB]

Can i do anything further to mitigate these threats, or is this just the state of things at the moment?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without a new CPU, no matter what people say, we will be always vulnerable. The problem is at hw level.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best source of information regarding Ubuntu-specific mitigations of Meltdown and Spectre is [the dedicated page in their security knowledge base](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/SpectreAndMeltdown). The information there matches what you’re seeing:

- your CPU hasn’t been updated to support IBRS/IBPB, so the mitigations for Spectre variant 2 aren’t functional;
- Meltdown and Spectre variant 1 are mitigated.

Regarding your CPU, there was [an updated microcode package](https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3531-1), but that caused regressions and [was reverted](https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3531-2). Your motherboard manufacturer might have a firmware update available to address the issue; installing that would enable the Spectre variant 2 mitigations.

Retpoline support isn’t included yet but might come later to address Spectre variant 2 as well.

As [Rui](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/138261/rui-f-ribeiro) [points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419622/still-vulnerable-after-spectremeltdown-ubuntu-kernel-3-13-0-141-generic-update#comment754115_419622), these updates shouldn’t lull you into a false of security, there are probably other similar vulnerabilities waiting to be discovered (if they haven’t already been!). In any case, you should always consider that computers can’t be trusted...

Comment: In any case, I have considered for many years the Intel platform cannot be trusted for several reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Quite a mess i see. My servers are on DigitalOcean VM's so i will have to make a risk manegement plan probably. Seems like you can't have it all as of right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can check any distro for "meltdown" by running
    "dmesg|grep isolation"
If PTI is enabled then the output should be:
    "Kernel/User page tables isolation: enabled"
On Devuan I had to enable it as follows:
Check if your vendor has patched your Kernel with PTI!
    "grep -i "isolation" /boot/config-*"
If it shows
   "CONFIG_PAGE_TABLE_ISOLATION=y"
Then you are in luck!
Enable PTI in Devuan by setting "pti=on" in kernel boot params:
Add "pti=on" to "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT" in "/etc/default/grub" and run:
   "update-grub"
Reboot and check again!
To mitigate against all Intel CPU's bugs the microcode must be updated as mentioned before in the post.
My i3 laptop is 8 years old! Any chance for a firmware update :-/